# Is there a way to get the `jid` inside a `sidekiq_retry_in` block?

Tags: ruby, sidekiq

Is there a way to get the `jid` inside a `sidekiq_retry_in` block?

```
sidekiq_retry_in do |count, exception| do
  # Cannot access jid or job["jid"]
end
```

Comment: Maybe? https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/34fe9149460f6cfe8951da1fb4f73dec2f4543eb/lib/sidekiq/worker.rb#L135 But a quick glance doesn't reveal how, and my gut says no.

Comment: did you try `self.jid` ?

Comment: I guess it's because there's no `jid` on that 'level'. I mean, which job's ID would you want to get here? The last that failed? Some of the previous ones?

Comment: Good comment @MarekLipka I had not thought of that, I was assuming it could be the one just crashed from the exception, but now you say that I think I understand.

Answer (score 2):

No, by design.  That method should perform a calculation and return a number, it should not be making network calls.

Comment: Thanks, but getting the `jid` isn't a network call. I think it is useful for logging, as we can correlate failed jobs.

Comment: IIRC `Sidekiq.logger.info` will work fine and should print the JID as context.